# Attempt to dismiss from view controller (UIModalViewController) while a presentation or dismiss is in progress

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, uiviewcontroller

I have just started working on ios.
I created a `Modalviewcontroller (VC1)` and presented another `modalViewcontroller (VC2)`.
There is a button `(dismiss)` on VC2 which will have to dismiss both viewcontrollers.

The way i know is call :-

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

in VC2
then call the same in VC1

So i created a delegate which tells me if dismiss is clicked in VC2.
so when dismiss is clicked:-

i call

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

in VC2
then that delegate method takes me to VC1
where I again call

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

This method was perfectly working till i was using the app in ios9
when i shifted to ios7 i started getting the warning and VC1 was not getting dismissed.

Please let me know why is this happening.

So the part which works for me as told in comments.

```
[self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
```

Comment: using delegate - pass the close method call to VC 1. In it call self dismissModal and in the completion parameter, dismiss VC1 too

Comment: Hi according to you ..  [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }]; should work

Comment: yes, it should.

Comment: @Shubhank Thanks man it worked..!!!

Answer (score 0):

So, error tells you exactly what happened. You trying to dismiss VC1, while your VC2 dismissing. By putting `dismissViewControllerAnimated` into delegate method does not guarantee that VC1 will be dismissed before, instead of that you should call your `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` in completion block after first dismiss, so your code will look like that:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                         completion:^{
                             [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                         }];
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be self.presentedviewcontroller in first dismissal.

Comment: How many animations do you want to see?  The way to see only one is to call `self dismiss...` on the view controller that presented VC1 (the view controller you wish to have visible after the dismissal).